# Select a cell and macro select the range of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I select A1 or A6 and Macro selects the whole range "A:A"...
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Normally you don't need to `Select`. What do you actually want to do? Are you looking for `ActiveCell.EntireColumn`?

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, perhaps you are looking for the [`Worksheet.SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event?

Comment: Man, ActiveCell.EntireColumn worked fine!!!! this is what I was looking for all this time and it was so simple. Love ya